SimpleListFilter and M2M fields as JSON
My setup contains Product information that come from a JSON field and are linked to a Page  in a m2m relation (Page like in a catalogue).
class Page(models.Model):
    ... 
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="%(class)s_name", related_query_name="product_page_qs", blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    data = models.JSONField()

I created a SimpleListFilter with text search to get a list of all pages that contain a given product (works just fine):
class PageProductSearch(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = "product"
    parameter_name = "product"
    template = "search_filter.html"

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return ((None, None),)

    def choices(self, changelist):
        super().choices(changelist)
        return (*self.lookup_choices,)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        value = self.value()
        if value:
            return queryset.filter(products=value)

My problem here is, that I have to know the product.id in order to search for products. How can I extend my queryset filtering to search for a key in the jsonField?
I tried:

queryset.filter(products__contain=value) but got django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'contain' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted. This might be because I am on SQLite.
using Q and regex: queryset.filter(Q(data__regex=r'"name":.*"test"')) but this always leads to empty querysets. I liked the regex idea tough, because it is insensitive to data elements that might not contain the key name.


Don't use JSON blobs: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/non-atomic-jsonfield-s.html

This ship has sailed some years ago unfortunately ... I am stuck with this database.

@xlc: an idea could be to add extra fields to the Products, then perform a data migration to move data out of the blob to the fields.

There is like a common key "name" for almost (!) all of the fields. but most of the keys in the JSON are custom per user. From this point of view jsonField made sense I guess.
